# Duplicate values - Stateless Valuewhen attempt

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to accomplish a stateless Valuewhen function. However, I'm getting duplicate values and I can't seem to figure out why. I only need the unique values to use with line.new later

Obviously, the plot chars are only for Troubleshooting & debugging

```
SupPerf = (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3]) ? low[2] : na

float SupVal = na
float SupVal1 = na
for i = 1 to 200
    if (SupPerf[i])
        SupVal1 := SupPerf[i]
        break 

plotchar(SupPerf[0], "SupPerf0", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[1], "SupPerf1", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[2], "SupPerf2", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[3], "SupPerf3", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[5], "SupPerf4", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[6], "SupPerf5", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[7], "SupPerf6", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupPerf[8], "SupPerf7", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)

plotchar(SupVal1[0], "SupVal0", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[1], "SupVal1", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[2], "SupVal2", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[3], "SupVal3", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[4], "SupVal4", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[5], "SupVal5", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[6], "SupVal6", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[7], "SupVal7", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[8], "SupVal8", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[9], "SupVal9", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(SupVal1[10], "SupVal10", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! :)

Hopefully, this is efficient... might be a better way, but it works great now!

```
i_suplncnt = input(2, "Support")

f_drawline(val) =>
    var int lncnt = 0
    var line ln = na
    ln := line.new(x1 = bar_index-200,
     y1 = val,
     x2 = bar_index,
     y2 = val,
     xloc = xloc.bar_index,
     extend = extend.both,
     color = color.maroon)
    
    
var line sup_ln = na
sup_ln := (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3]) ? f_drawline(low[2]) : na
sup_lncnt = 0
for i = 1 to 500
    if not na(sup_ln[i])
        sup_lncnt := sup_lncnt + 1
        if sup_lncnt > i_suplncnt
            line.delete(sup_ln[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your objective is, but no need for a `for` loop to reproduce your current logic. See method 2 in here:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)

// Method 1.
SupPerf = (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3]) ? low[2] : na
float SupVal = na
float SupVal1 = na
for i = 1 to 200
    if (SupPerf[i])
        SupVal1 := SupPerf[i]
        break 
plot(SupVal1)

// Method 2.
var float SupPerf2 = na
if (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3])
    SupPerf2 := low[2]
plot(SupPerf2[1], "SupPerf2", color.blue, 6, transp = 80)

// For validation
plotchar((hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3]), "(hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3])", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish is asking "how many lines" and using a "line.new" to draw lines and the "line.delete" to remove lines. My current strategy doesn't get a unique value to draw, determining the delete line is hard.
`lncnt = input(defval=2)
f_findval_sup() =>
    var float SupVal = na
    if (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3])
    SupVal := low[2]
    SupVal
SupVal = f_findval_sup()
var line Supln = na
Supln := line.new(x1 = bar_index-200,y1 = SupVal, x2 = bar_index,y2 = SupVal,xloc = xloc.bar_index,extend = extend.both,color = color.maroon)
line.delete(Supln[lncnt])`

Comment: Also, tried this:
`
keepLastLines = input(5)
SupVal1 = (hlc3[2] <= hlc3[1] and hlc3[2] <= hlc3[3]) ? low[2] : na
var line ln = na
lineCount = 0
ln := line.new(x1 = bar_index-200,y1 = SupVal1,x2 = bar_index,y2 = SupVal1,xloc = xloc.bar_index,extend = extend.both,color = color.maroon)
for i = 1 to 50
    if not na(ln[i])
        lineCount := lineCount + 1
        if lineCount > keepLastLines
            line.delete(ln[i])
`
still can't seem to only get the lines with unique values.